# How to detect tab change from the active tab page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

While searching in the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#events) to find how to detect tab change, I found that there is the `ionTabsDidChange` event that is directly linked to the `ion-tabs` component.

My purpose is slightly different in the way that I need to listen to the tab change from the page/component related to the tab itself, and use some of its data.

For example, if I have a component named `TabXPage`, I wonder if there is a way to create a method that helps to listen to the tab change, something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabx',
  templateUrl: './tabx.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabx.page.scss'],
})
export class TabXPage implements OnInit {

    //...

    onTabChange() {
        // Execute tab change actions using some data that EXISTS IN TabXPage
    }

}
```

I looked upon [Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), but I did not find any applicable event since the page is preserved in the same state while navigating through the Ionic tabs.

Comment: Did you try `ionTabsWillChange`?  That seems like it would work for your case.

Comment: `ionTabsDidChange`  and `ionTabsWillChange` are both applicable on `ion-tabs`. I am looking for a way to listen to the tab change from the page itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using [Ionic lifecycle hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/lifecycle/angular), I am not sure if it's the best regarding the subject but it's working for my case.

I used simply the `ionViewDidLeave` page event:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabx',
  templateUrl: './tabx.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabx.page.scss'],
})
export class TabXPage implements OnInit {
    //...

    ionViewDidLeave() {
        console.log("TabX is exited")
    }
}
```

Comment: Definetly the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

in ionic 3 i achieved by using ionSelect() and ionChange() method.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (ionSelect)="myMethod()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" (ionChange)="myMethod()"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```